# Prevent user from chaning tokens within input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to prevent the change of certain elements, tokens, within a textarea with javascript or jquery? For instance I have this string  in an input

this is normal text  {this can't be changed 1}.  This is more text.  {This can't be changed 2 }. And some more text

If a user tries to change text within the curly brackets I want to prevent that from happening.

I thought of finding the indexes of the start and stop indexes of the tokens and when a user tries to change an element, I would see if it falls within that range.

Is there a different approach that I can use?

Comment: Haha, thats a wacky little requirement there. You can add a change handler to the text area, which saves the current text of the text box, and then decide whether or not you want the changes to actually occur.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? I'd say it could get quite complicated to catch all possible ways the input-value could be changed. Why not simply use multiple intputs, and display the "not-to-change" texts as plain html between them? The user experience will be the same, but a lot less hassle for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to read everything between {} into an array when the page loads. Then when the form submits do that same thing again and compare them to make sure they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a regular expression that validates the validity of the text. on every `keydown` event in the textarea revalidate the regex and notify the user / prevent the keypress.

As text can also be changes in other ways (paste, autocomplete, etc.) you should also validate on `change` event of the textarea.